# Скрипт на Python для переименования файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

Мне надо  переименовать все фотографии, лежащие у меня в папке, на 1.jpg, 2.jpg и так далее.

```
import os
path = raw_input("C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Фото")
listOfFiles = os.listdir(path)
countOfFiles = len(listOfFiles)
os.chdir(path)
for i in range(0, countOfFiles):
    os.rename(path+listOfFiles[i], str(i+1)+'.jpg')
```

Этот скрипт вбивает ошибку.

Comment: Какая-то каша в коде.. У вас используется `raw_input`, что относится только к питону2, но метка python3. Какая-то фигня с кавычками и слешами. Кавычки открыты и закрыты неправильно. Слеши тут сделают экранирование, да и лишние пробелы в пути. И какую ошибку скрипт показывает? Ошибки разные бывают. Добавьте, пожалуста, в вопрос стек ошибки (кнопка `править`)

Comment: Да и зачем вам в консоли показывать путь до Фото?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему или ошибку** и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import os

path = r"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Фото"

i = 1

for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    # Имя файла и его формат
    base_name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)

    # Нужны файлы определенного формата
    if ext.lower() not in ['.jpg', '.jpeg']:
        continue

    # Полный путь к текущему файлу
    abs_file_name = os.path.join(path, file_name)

    # Полный путь к текущему файлу с новым названием
    new_abs_file_name = os.path.join(path, str(i) + ext)
    
    os.rename(abs_file_name, new_abs_file_name)

    i += 1
```

Comment: От такая ошиька получилась.!                                                                                               
RESTART: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\LessonPhoto.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\LessonPhoto.py", line 21, in <module>
    os.rename(abs_file_name, new_abs_file_name)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Невозможно создать файл, так как он уже существует: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Фото\\102.jpg' -> 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Locall\\Фото\\2.jpg'
>>>

Comment: Спасибо помогло)

Comment: @АндрійГавриляк, разобрались с ошибкой?

Comment: да, там было несколько фото с одинаковыми названиями , я начал отсчет не с 1, а с 1000! и помогло .Спасибо!

Comment: если заменить path, на такую:
path = input()
то очень удобно использовать для любой папки

Comment: @vbujym, можно и дальше развивать и использовать путь из аргумента, подключив argparse (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prog)